# Clion: How to define debug level?

Tags: c++, clion

I have the following debug statements in my code:

```
#if (DEBUG_LEVEL > 0)
        printf("ITER %d\n", iter);
#endif
```

How can I define debug level in Clion debugger? And do I need to use CMAKE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the following to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

   ```
   if (DEBUG_LEVEL)
       add_definitions(-DDEBUG_LEVEL=${DEBUG_LEVEL})
   endif()
   ```

   It basically says: "If you have "DEBUG_LEVEL" CMake variable defined, pass the `DEBUG_LEVEL=X` preprocessor definition to the compiler"
2. Pass the desired value of the variable (e.g. `-DDEBUG_LEVEL=1`) to CMake (in CLion it can be done via `Options | Build, Execution, Deployment | CMake | CMake options`).

This way you need to edit your CMakeLists.txt once, but then you can change the actual value without touching the source code.

I guess you can hack it around without touching CMakeLists.txt at all, but the approach above seems more straightforward and idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes a global variable can solve this issue but your solution is much preferable :D